# PHP : instantiate a Class and using methods of another Class

Tags: php, class, methods, instantiation

I have a class, named A. I have another class named B that extends A.
I must instantiate A, and not B, but I need to use the methods in B too. How can I do this?

```
Class A
{
    public function foo() { }
}

Class B extends A
{
    public function bar() { }
}

$a = new A();
$a->bar();
```

I know that this is not possible, but I need of a solution for this.

PS: I wish the title of this question is correct.

Comment: why can you not instantiate `B`? I think there lies your actual problem.

Comment: I have the impression that it's a design problem rather than a syntax problem.

Comment: Care to elaborate why you can't instantiate B?

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = new A();
$a->bar();
```

Will give you fatal error. Because `bar()` is not a method of class `A`. 
So you can't call this using `A` class's object.

This will work fine:

```
Class A
{
   public function foo() { }
}

Class B extends A
{
   public static function bar() {  }
}

$a = new A();
B::bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you just misunderstood the syntax of PHP (**[Which can be rather confusing sometimes](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/)**)

The `extends` keyword does not *extend* the parent class (`A`), but does create a new class `B` which is a child of `A`. `B` inherits `A`'s methods, but `A` itself is not altered.

Answer (score -1):

Can the methods in B become static?

```
Class A
{
    public function foo() { }
}

Class B extends A
{
    public static function bar2() { }
}

$a = new A();
$a->bar();
B::bar2();
```

obviously it would make sense to name it something different, as B::bar() is overriding the A::bar() implementation.

I think you might have your structure slightly off. Try to abstract what you want as a reusable code snippet into its own routine.